# plot only area where multiple 2D lines crossed

Tags: python, matplotlib, intersection

I have connected multiple data points using 2D lines with different colors. But in case of many lines, it is hard to differentiate where most of the lines overlap or intersect.
For example, here is my script, and I have plotted a few red and black lines.
How can we extract only the area where we have high density of these crossing red lines (maybe user defined crossing numbers?
Any suggestions will be highly appreciated.

```
        ax.scatter(rcv[:,0], rcv[:,1], c='b', marker='v',s=190,label= "End")
        ax.scatter(src[:,0], src[:,1], c='r', marker='*',s=120,label= "Start")

        if status=="High":
            x_values = [x1, x2]
            y_values = [y1, y2]

            plt.plot(x_values, y_values, 'k-', linewidth=0.5,alpha=0.5)
            fig.canvas.draw()
        else:
            x_values = [x1, x2]
            y_values = [y1, y2]

            plt.plot(x_values, y_values, 'r-', linewidth=0.5,alpha=0.5)
            fig.canvas.draw()
```

[image]